# What does かこっかな mean?

Tags: meaning, words

I see this used but I can't figure out what it means.

Comment: Please add more context. Where do you see it used and by who?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

かこっかな is a more casual way of かこうかな(書こうかな), and 〜うかな means "I'm wondering if I should 〜."
So the phrase means "I'm wondering if I should write something". I don't know the whole sentence but かこっかな means this.